# What's the best way to save user's UI preferences in Sitecore application?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

We have web application that uses Sitecore. There are the elements of user interface written in AngularJS. I'd like to save some user's UI preferences, for example the type of view (list or thumbnail) so that when user run the application next time he should see his desired type of view.

I'm wondering what's the best strategy to achieve this? Is it better to save preferences in some kind of locale storage or session storage or in some way directly in Sitecore? The saving preferences has to be connected with particular user.

Comment: Maybe contact facets are something for you http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/xDB/contact-facets/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to keep your application portable between CMS platforms, I would recommend using your own custom storage, or perhaps using your own collection in Mongo so that you can lift and shift to another platform more easily. This also keeps you safe from any potential upgrade issues when moving from one version of Sitecore to another.

You could use the Core DB, since that is where Sitecore stores user data, but that membership info is intended for data about users that you can see in the Sitecore User Manager. If your users are authenticating against Sitecore, this might make sense.

If you are using a third-party authentication system of some kind, then it probably makes the most sense to keep your preferences stored in your primary user storage behind the system where you are authenticating.